# Changing Flex registration point from upper left corner to center

Tags: apache-flex

I need help with Flex.
I want to learn how you can change the registration point for the Canvas.
I want to make a zoom of this component, but the point registration in the upper left corner! How do I move to the center?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Place your Canvas in a container object and center it.
2. Leave the registration point as it is and when zooming, change the x and y coordinates to the left/top.

There might be a "proper" solution though.

Hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: the first option will not work!
but second, I do not know how to implement it))) do not tell me the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's going to help to 'center' the registration point, but whatever.  This is how you do it:

**Flex 3**

```
<mx:Canvas clipContent="false">
    <mx:Box width="400" height="400" x="-200" y="-200" backgroundColor="#000000" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

**Flex 4**

```
<s:Group clipAndEnableScrolling="false">
    <s:BorderContainer width="400" height="400" x="-200" y="-200" backgroundColor="#000000" />
</s:Group>
```

But however, there are other problems, like if I want to center the canvas/group, it won't work properly if you use vertical/horizontalCenter because the content within it is off.  Personally, I think this workaround is idiotic if you just want to zoom in.  It's a fairly simple operation.  If you need it to be centered while it's zooming in, you can always change the x/y position of whatever you're zooming into.  The calculation is fairly simple to find the center of your components:

```
var center:Point = new Point(component.x + component.width/2, component.y + component.height/2);
```